# Adding space between each column underline css

Tags: css

I want to add space between each column of my table, but unable to do so,
- like a gap between each underline.

I seen these posts https://www.bootply.com/PN8edIkglD, but not able to fix it

this is code I have tried

```
.rbcrosstab #CR > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #005691 !important;
    height: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
} 
.rbcrosstab #CR > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #24A3CC !important;
    height: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
} 
.rbcrosstab #CR > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #88BB6C !important;
    height: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add padding left/right tot he element, just like you added padding top/bottom? PS, where is your MCVE, including HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Using pseudo element :after to create a seperate element. Hard to do this with border-bottom. Use calc() to get the width then.
Hope that helps and best of luck!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            thead td:after {
                background: red;
                content: '';
                width: calc(100% - 5px);
                height: 3px;
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Volcano Name</td>
                    <td>Location</td>
                    <td>Last Major Eruption</td>
                    <td>Type of Eruption</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Mt. Lassen</td>
                <td>California</td>
                <td>1914-17</td>
                <td>Explosive Eruption</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mt. Hood</td>
                <td>Oregon</td>
                <td>1790s</td>
                <td>Pyroclastic flows and Mudflows</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mt .St. Helens</td>
                <td>Washington</td>
                <td>1980</td>
                <td>Explosive Eruption</td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </body>
</html>
```